# CSS hover - How do I get it to change two nested divs

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to get a hover trigger done on the td which will change the entire background of the class "selectTemplate" change. But whats happening currently is - the `{{description}}` changes correctly, but the `{{name}}` stays the same.

I want both `{{name}}` & `{{description}}` to change when hovered over.

HTML

```
<table class="templateList templatepolicy-table">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#items}}
            <div id="TemplateItem">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="{{sequence}}" class="selectTemplate">
                                <div class="TemplateName">
                                    {{name}}
                                </div>
                                {{description}}
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        {{/items}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS

```css
table.templatepolicy-table 
{
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background-color: white;
}

table.templatepolicy-table .TemplateName  
{
    background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232); 
    color: #2779AC;
    font-weight:bolder;
}

table.templatepolicy-table td 
{
    color: #656565;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

table.templatepolicy-table td:hover
{ 
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #2779AC;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last selector to this:

```css
table.templatepolicy-table td:hover,
table.templatepolicy-table td:hover .TemplateName {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #2779AC;
}
```

Comment: This will change both at the same time or just which ever you are hoving over?

Comment: @gabeDel: It'll change both the `td` and its `div` as you hover over the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.TemplateName` has a `background-color` set, so that rule being obeyed. You have to override that:

```css
table.templatepolicy-table td:hover,
table.templatepolicy-table td:hover .TemplateName {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #2779AC;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is basically the same as Kolink's answer, but since I has already written it...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you that if you use, td:hover it would not work on lower versons of IE.

Now regarding your css not working, let me explain the reason to you. Your main issue is while hovering over the `<td>` the entire background color of `class="selectTemplate" or the td` is not changing. Actually its changing but as you have defined a background color of `<div class="TemplateName">` with this `table.templatepolicy-table .TemplateName { background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232); }`, its overlapping the changed background color.

Hence to get this sort out you have to change the background color of `<div class="TemplateName">` too with the hover. As previous answers says the code would be :-

```css
table.templatepolicy-table td:hover,
table.templatepolicy-table td:hover .TemplateName {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #2779AC;
}
```

Hope this clarifies your queries.